# What is the minimum amount for Windows Phone 8 In App Purchases?

Tags: in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8

I've searched and searched but it would appear my Google-fu is weak.

Does anyone know what the **minimum** purchase price is for an IAP consumable on WP8?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, IAP products can be sold for free (0.0$) and up to 499.99$. Free IAP items are OK and are even a user experience best practice in order to get consumers used to the idea of in-app purchases in your app.

[image: WP8 IAP products]

Here's a list of all allowed WP8 product prices in USD: 0.00$, 0.99$, 1.29$, 1.49$, 1.99$, 2.49$, 2.99$, 3.49$, 3.99$, 4.49$, 4.99$, 5.99$, 6.99$, 7.99$, 8.99$, 9.99$, 10.99$, 11.99$, 12.99$, 13.99$, 14.99$, 15.99$, 16.99$, 17.99$, 18.99$, 19.99$, 20.99$, 21.99$, 22.99$, 23.99$, 24.99$, 25.99$, 26.99$, 27.99$, 28.99$, 29.99$, 30.99$, 31.99$, 32.99$, 33.99$, 34.99$, 35.99$, 36.99$, 37.99$, 38.99$, 39.99$, 40.99$, 41.99$, 42.99$, 43.99$, 44.99$, 45.99$, 46.99$, 47.99$, 48.99$, 49.99$, 50.99$, 59.99$, 69.99$, 79.99$, 89.99$, 99.99$, 109.99$, 119.99$, 129.99$, 139.99$, 149.99$, 159.99$, 169.99$, 179.99$, 189.99$, 199.99$, 209.99$, 219.99$, 229.99$, 239.99$, 249.99$, 299.99$, 349.99$, 399.99$, 449.99$, 499.99$.